# ListFragment и BackStack

Tags: android, android-studio, backstack

Всем привет. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Хочу сделать так, чтобы когда пользователь нажимал на кнопку "Назад" - открывался предыдущий фрагмент.

Использую один layout и 2 класса. В layout просто вставлен фрагмент, ссылающийся на класс, который наследует ListFragment:

```
<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="com.test.fragment.ListFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"/>
```

В MainActivity тоже всё типично:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Проблема в классе, наследующем ListFragment. Вместо показа предыдущего фрагмента, приложение закрывается:

```
public class ListFragment extends android.app.ListFragment {
FragmentTransaction fTrans;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.testArray1, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    setListAdapter(adapter1);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null);
    switch (position)
    {
        case 0:
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.testArray2, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
            setListAdapter(adapter2);
            break;
        case 1:
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
    }
    fTrans.commit();
}
```

Очень прошу помочь. Заранее огромное спасибо.

Comment: Нигде не видно в вашем коде как вы используете два фрагмента.

Comment: Для ListFragment не нужно делать layout-фрагменты.

Есть класс MainActivity, ссылающийся на единственный layout-файл. Есть второй класс, наследующий ListFragment. Он и подставляет в единственный layout-файл список.

Если что-то не так понял, прошу поправить меня.

Answer (score 1):

Данный метод добавляет в стэк:

```
addToBackStack(null);
```

Это возвращается назад на один:

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, подскажите, после чего (или куда) вставлять эти методы. Я себе уже всю голову сломал.

Comment: А как должно работать? Кнопка назад в Toolbar или ActionBar?

Comment: При нажатии на кнопку телефона (возможно эта панель и называется ToolBar). Вот фото: http://s019.radikal.ru/i642/1511/ad/3480066da034.jpg

Comment: Ну вообще, если есть addToBackStack то должно работать, если только в активности не перегружен метод onBackPressed()